# Content-length node.js superagent

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, superagent

I try to send POST request to another site (API).
My request:

```
request
        .post(url)
        .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
        .set('Content-Disposition','form-data; name="photo"; filename="'+img+'.jpg"')
        .attach('file',memsPath+img+'.jpg')
        .field('photo',img+'.jpg')
        .end(callbackSA);
```

request - is a [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests),
memsPath and img - variables for my image.

Server response is 411, need content-length. How I can set this length?

Comment: SuperAgent already takes care of setting `Content-Length`. Are you sure the path to your image is correct?

Comment: Hi, Ryan! How I can check it? if I type any path (mems/blabla/img.jpg) - node.js app crashed with "ENOENT - file not found". But with this path - no errors. It's absolute path from /home/user/.../imgname.jpg May be I need another way to set path?

Comment: That's a good point. I was just wondering because your code doesn't look too different from the examples given on the SuperAgent website, and when I checked the source code for `request.end()`, I saw that it set the `Content-Length` automatically. Does this happen for posting to every website?